# Extend model of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listview

I use entity framework which generates me model. It contains some "static data". I extend it like this:

```
public partial class automaty
{
    public bool ConnectionAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

Field ConnectionAvailable determines whether device is "pingable".

In MainWindow I have ListView called listView and method Refresh():

```
void Refresh()
    {
        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                var automats = Controller.Automats;
                listView.ItemsSource = automats;

                listView.UpdateLayout();
            }));
        }).Start();
    }
```

which is called every 30seconds. It works good but I want to show also device status. So I've created thread with infinity loop that pings every device:

```
void PingLoop()
    {
        while (isInPingLoop)
        {
            var automats = listView.Items.Cast<automaty>().ToList();
            foreach (var automat in automats)
            {
                if (isInPingLoop == false)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var connection = Tools.HasConnection(automat.Adres_IP);

                automat.ConnectionAvailable = connection;
            }
        }
    }
```

In View it is binded:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ConnectionAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToYesNoConverter}, ConverterParameter='pack://application:,,,/MachinesManager;component/Images/green-circle.png|pack://application:,,,/MachinesManager;component/Images/red-circle.png'}">
```

My problem is that status circle isn't refreshing. I know that PingLoop set ConnectionAvailable field to true when it can ping, but it isn't shown on screen.

Comment: In what thread is `PingLoop` running? Is it on the UI thread? If so your binding changes will never propagate to the UI view.

Comment: I've managed with it by adding new bool array which contains states of machines and after refreshing source of listview I'm just assigning those values to objects.